# How to pass Datarow array of values to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I've Datarow Collection Array of strings.I want to pass this array to javascript and do operations on them.How do I do this

Comment: What kind of operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to make use of [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx).

Here is a simple function that will turn any serializable object into JSON:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;

public static string ToJson<T>(this T input)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(stream, input);
        var jsonText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        return jsonText;
    }
}
```

Here is an example where I used it on a `string[]`:

```
static void Main()
{
    var input = new[] { "one", "two", @"three ""with quotes""!", "↑" };
    Console.WriteLine(input.ToJson());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The output is, as expected:

```
["one","two","three \"with quotes\"!","↑"]
```

Now, in your question you mention `DataRow`, so you need to turn a `DataRow` object into something you can pass in here. I think the `ItemArray` property is what you are looking for:

```
public string DataRowToJson(DataRow dr)
{
    return dr.ItemArray.ToJson();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping you using ASP.NET controls for things other than HTML. I regularly find myself using repeaters to create Javascript arrays.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<asp:Repeater ID="WhateverRepeater" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
var data = [
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>"<%# Container.DataItem %>"</ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>, 
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
];
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

</script>
```

Bind your data to that repeater and it'll dump out a Javascript array, like so:

```
var data = [
    "string0",
    "string1",
    "string2",
    "string3"
];
```

You can then use this in your client-side code like any other JS array.

(Doing this without a compiler present, so some of the details may be off)

Comment: Ouch! Try running this on an array of strings that contain double-quotes :)

Comment: Ugh, Posting too late :  ) 
Much prefer your solution anyway. Have an upvote, sir.